# PHP csv upload file not on the server

Tags: php, csv, upload

I wrote a simple script to upload a csv file and then update a database table. However, even though I am getting a temp $_FILES['update']['tmp_name'] path, the file is not at this location on the server. Does anyone know what this means? could it be a permissions issue? This is a Godaddy shared hosting account.

Here's my form and the handler (the database piece is not in place yet. I'm just trying to get file contents at this point):

```
<div class="admin-section" style="margin-left:10%;">
    <?php
        if ( !empty($_POST['uploadFile']) ) {
            $name = $_FILES['update']['name'];
            echo $_FILES['update']['type'] . '<br />';
            echo $_FILES['update']['size'] . '<br />';
            $path = $_FILES['update']['tmp_name'];
            echo $_FILES['update']['error'] . '<br />';

            $file = $path . '/' . $name;
            $file_open = fopen($file, 'r');
            $data = fgetcsv( $file_open, 1000, ',');
            print_r($data);
        }
    ?>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="#" method=post>
        <label>Select a CSV or XLS file to up load from your computer</label><br />
        <p>
            <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000" />
            <input type="hidden" name="uploadFile" value="yes" />
            <input type=file name=update />
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type=submit name=Upload />
        </p>
    </form>
</div>
```

The error I get is **fopen(/tmp/php05Lebo/certificate-users.csv): failed to open stream: No such file or directory**, and sure enough, that folder does not exist in /tmp. Thanks!

Comment: you never bothered checking if an upload was actually successful. there's a `['error']` parameter in $_FILES for a reason. You are also accessing the **CLIENT SIDE** filename. uploads to the server go into a randomish-named tmp file, which is listed in `['tmp_name']`. so your `$file` is totally wrong.

Comment: Hi Marc - I do check for errors (notice that I echoed that variable) and it produced a "0". So no errors. I'm not sure why your are saying that I am using the client site path. My $path variable is the tmp_name. Please clarify if I am misunderstanding you. Thanks

Comment: $path contains the ENTIRE path to the temp file, e.t. `/tmp/this/that/asdfasdfasdf`. you're adding that to the client-side filename, producing `/tmp/this/that/asdfasdfasdf/kittens.jpg`, which does NOT exist on your server.

Comment: OK. I see that I confused the temp name with the temp folder. I though the  uploaded file would look like this: tmp_name/name. But it's just tmp_name

Answer (score 0):

You never moved the temp file to the $file path, so your $file is invalid. Either use `move_uploaded_file()` to rename the temp file and save it on your server or if you don't care about accessing the file after the initial upload, set `$file = $_FILES['update']['tmp_name']`

```
<?php
    if ( !empty($_POST['uploadFile']) ) {
        $name = $_FILES['update']['name'];
        echo $_FILES['update']['type'] . '<br />';
        echo $_FILES['update']['size'] . '<br />';
        $path = $_FILES['update']['tmp_name'];
        echo $_FILES['update']['error'] . '<br />';
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['update']['tmp_name']),$name){
            $file_open = fopen($name, 'r');
            $data = fgetcsv( $file_open, 1000, ',');
            print_r($data);
        }else
           echo 'Unable to upload file';
    }
?>
```

Comment: This will upload the file to the current directory by the way. If you want it somewhere else prepend the path before $name

Comment: Thanks ksealey. The problem was actually that I was using the tmp_name variable incorrectly. For a csv upload I don't want to save the file on the server. I just want it loaded to the temp directory for as long as it takes to get the csv data and that's it.